# Creating multiple relationships of the same type between two nodes in Neo4j using Cypher

Tags: java, rest, neo4j, cypher

Is it possible to create multiple relationships of the same type with different properties between two nodes?

For example: for a movie with a double role:

```
Actor--acts{charactername : "hank"}--> movie.
```

and also the same actor, does another character in the same movie say, FRED

```
Actor-- acts{ charactername: "Fred"}-->Movie
```

.

Is there a way to do so using Cypher?
I am using the REST API, Neo4j 2.0.2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple of relations of the same type with or without different properties are allowed between two nodes.

This Cypher statement will create acts relations for all character names passed in:

```
MATCH (actor:Actor {id:3}),(movie:Movie { id:4})
FOREACH (character IN ['Hank', 'Fred']| 
         CREATE actor-[:acts { charactername:character }]->movie)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i am looking for something dynamic like whenever user comments on some post then a new "COMMENTED " relationship is formed between the user and the post. Each relation having its own property as the posting time. Is that possible. thank you.

Comment: Yes, just whenever a user comments, create a relation between the user and the post and set relevant properties.

Comment: Thanks Luanne. Your answers saved my day.